# `setInterval` Apparent Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, setinterval

When I open the HTML with the below JavaScript, `starting timer` gets logged in the console, but then my mouse icon just spins.

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log("starting timer");
    var n = 0;
    var id = setInterval(function() { console.log("hello"); n++ }, 100);
    while(true) {
        if( n > 5 ) {
              clearInterval(id);
              break;
        }
    }
    console.log("finished timer");
}
```

Am I creating some type of infinite loop here?

Comment: get rid of the `while`, check `n` when you increment, and clear if needed there

Comment: @charlietfl - for my learning, why must I change the `while(true) if(n > 5)` to `while(n > 5)`?

Comment: +KevinMeredith that's not what he/she wants you to do. He wants you to have the checking code in the setInterval

Comment: that `while` will run many thousands or 100's of thousands of times a second is why...choking up resources

Comment: and (correct me if wrong), but once the thread enters the `while(true)`, it won't yield to the `setInterval` code. Bottom line - *infinite loop*.

Comment: that's more than likely true too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript/DOM is single threaded by design.

And while JS is spinning this loop of yours:

```
while(true) {
      ...
}
```

no other JS code gets executed including that callback you provide in setInterval() and so n is always zero.

Therefore, yes, you have infinite loop there.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The thread is stuck in the infinite loop of `while(true)`. Thus it never yields to the `setInterval` code. [side question - would any browser yield the thread here?]

Comment: setInterval is a kind of loop by itself - it calls your callback until you stop it. So you can just remove your while() and move `if( n > 5 ) ..` into interval handler function.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that JavaScript is single-threaded. (This is a feature.) Your setInterval function will not execute until that window.onload function returns, which it never will because the break never occurs because n never gets incremented.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `while(true)` statement is re-running as fast as possible. As soon as it's done, it starts again, and there is no time left for anything else, freezing up the browser. You should have the setInterval check inside of itself. e.g:

```
window.onload=function(){
    console.log('starting timer');
    var n=0;
    var id=setInterval(function(){console.log('hello');n++;if(n>5){
        clearInterval(id);
        console.log('finished timer');
    },100);
}
```

Comment: Is it that `there is no time left for anything else` or simply that the single, only thread never yields? Your language, as I understand, implies a context switch. [disclaimer: I don't know the answer]

Comment: [disclaimer: I don't either]