# setInterval usage causes strange infinite loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying a `map` lesson and got tripped up on `setInterval` causing an infinite loop. Since I am only going over a list with 5 elements, I don't understand why this is happening; it prints out all 5 numbers like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

over and over again forever with:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function delayedPrint(text, delay = 400) {
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(text);
    }, delay)
}

console.log('\nMap can take 1 argument, which is each item in the array:')

list.map(function(this_list_item) {
    delayedPrint(this_list_item);
});
```

but changing `delayedPrint(this_list_item);` to `console.log(this_list_item);` the code works as normal, printing each item 1 time.

Why does this infinite loop happen and how can I print these items with an arbitrary delay?  [`setInterval` Apparent Infinite Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810781/setinterval-apparent-infinite-loop) didn't help.

Comment: Right. That's what `setInterval()` is supposed to do.

Comment: why map if the result of map is never used (and beeing undefined  ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setTimeout` to call a function **once** with a delay.

`setInterval` will call that function an unlimited number of times every *delay* milliseconds.

If what you are trying to achieve is printing an item, then another after *delay* milliseconds, and so on, this is a way to achieve it (manually incrementing the delay for each item):

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var delay = 400;

function delayedPrint(text, delay = 1000) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(text);
    }, delay)
}

list.map(function(this_list_item, index) {
    delayedPrint(this_list_item, index * delay);
});
```

By the way, as Nina correctly points out, `map` may not be the best choice to convey what you are doing here, and `forEach` would be clearer:

```
list.forEach(function(this_list_item, index) {
    delayedPrint(this_list_item, index * delay);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is what [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is supposed to do:

> The setInterval() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin **repeatedly calls a function** or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.

What you want, however, is [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).